# Launch another application

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I need to launch from my c#/compact framework application another .net CF application, which is located in ProgramFiles folder. What should I use? wceload.exe or anything else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simply run your application using the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

class MyProcess
    {
void OpenApplication(string myFavoritesPath)
        {
            // Start Internet Explorer. Defaults to the home page.

            Process.Start("IExplore.exe");

        }
}
```